# Find the unique periodic solution of this equation whose period is $2\pi$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

How to find the unique periodic solution of the equation that period is $2\pi$? The equation: $$y''+2ay'+b^2y = \cos (x), \quad 0 \le a < b < 1$$

**My attempt:**

I've tried to solve it as non-homogeneous equation by the undetermined coefficients method but it didn't work out due to the undefined coefficients.

Comment: I've tried to solve it as non-homogeneous equation by the undetermined coefficients method but it didn't work out due to the undefined coefficients.

Comment: Always add your attempt in your question otherwise the question is eligible for deletion Bruh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for a solution of the form
$$
y=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x.
$$
Then
$$
y''+2ay'+b^2y=\big((b^2-1)c_1+2ac_2\big)\cos x+\big((b^2-1)c_2-2ac_1\big)\sin x=\cos x
$$
Hence $c_1,c_2$ should satisfy the system
$$
(b^2-1)c_1+2ac_2=1 \\ (b^2-1)c_2-2ac_1=0
$$